# How Can I access extension attributes with WinNT?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, active-directory

I am trying to make a web application that gives the user the privilege to edit a certain extension attribute in his AD account. WinNT ("WinNT://Domain/Username,user") was chosen because it allows a losely coupled access to Active Directory objects without the need to specify a domain controller or a fully qualified domain name. **The connection was successful but i wasn't able to retrieve the extension attribute "extension_attribute_10".**

Will WinNT be able to access the extension attribute ? if not is there any work arounds ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which attributes you want to retrieve in your DirectoryServices query.

See : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.aspx

Comment: sorry for the very late reply but the output of the directory searcher is **System.NotSupportedException: The provider does not support searching and cannot search WinNT**